# Make an ajax call after form checking

Tags: jquery

I have a form like this:

```
<form id="update_form_password">
    <label for="text-input">Nouveau mot de passe</label>
    <input type="password" id="customer_new_password" name="customer_new_password" class="form-control">
    <label for="text-input">Répétez le mot de passe</label>
    <input type="paswword" id="customer_repeat_password" name="customer_repeat_password" class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Enregistrer</button>
</form>
```

I'm using the [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org) to check is my forms are correctly filled.

My problem is to submit the form after the check.

So I have actually:

```
<script>
$('#update_form_password').validate({
    rules: {
        customer_new_password: "required",
        customer_repeat_password: {
            equalTo: "#customer_new_password"
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

But how to allow the form submitting and then continue my ajax calls ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: looking at that plugin, it seems it already handles that for you. It will prevent form submit if a rule is broken and let it submit otherwise(without any code on your part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the submitHandler option to make the ajax request, which will prevent the default form submit action also.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#update_form_password').validate({
        rules: {
            customer_new_password: "required",
            customer_repeat_password: {
                equalTo: "#customer_new_password"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            //something like
            $.ajax({
                url: 'url',
                type: 'post',
                data: $(form).serialize()
            })
        }
    });
});
```